# How can I make interactive (attach React to) a prerendered React app from the client side?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, client, prerender

I'd like to display a prerendered interactive app to the client (the server just sends the html).

I created a simple react app for a test, only a button which when pressed shows an alert dialog.

Then I made a build:

```
  npm run build
```

This created an index.html file in the build directory which displays the test app when opened.

This is good, but not interactive, so I guess I have to attach React to it somehow and call hydrate() from the client. (Is that correct? Does hydrate() work from the client side too?)

The problem is I don't know how should I invoke hydrate().

This is how render is invoked normally:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

but I can't use this with hydrate() from the client side, because client side JS does not know the `<App />` syntax. So my question is how can I invoke hydrate() in the browser, what should I put for the first argument instead of `<App />`?

```
ReactDOM.hydrate(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Can't you just put anything there? `<App />` could just `<div></div>`. That is just the component that ReactDOM will put on the 'root' element. So you can just put html... right?

Comment: I tried putting `'<div></div>'` there, but then the app content on the screen was simply replaced with the string `'<div></div>'`

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution and leave it for others as an answer.

There is no need to call hydrate() at all, everything works as is. The problem was the generated .js and .css files were refered in the index.html with the path `/static/...`

After fixing the paths it worked instantly, the generated app is interactive, the alert dialog shows up when the button is pressed.